# Bootstrap Collapse don't show if is below the window screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I just found this little problem, but the solution is slipping from my finger. I have a page with multiple sections collapsed, that I want to show when you click the right button.

Now, everything is working perfectly accordingly Bootstrap and is Js library, but I noticed, that when your screen is not big enough, you cannot see the the div expanded/shows.

Below the simple code from w3c school that should work for this example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Collaps 1</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo1" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <h2>Collaps 2</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <h2>Collaps 3</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo3" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried also to work with some js function that imply the scrollTop, like that

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#demo3).offset().top -200}, 500);
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [Bootstrap collapse documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#events), you can use Bootstrap collapse event to scroll the page when the div expands.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/35oz96qe/

```js
$(function() {
  $('#demo3').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#demo3').offset().top - 200
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Collaps 1</h2>
    <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">Simple collapsible</button>
    <div id="demo1" class="collapse">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <h2>Collaps 2</h2>
    <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">Simple collapsible</button>
    <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <h2>Collaps 3</h2>
    <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3">Simple collapsible</button>
    <div id="demo3" class="collapse">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Believe me, I tried it for hours... I didn't post my original code because i can't. But I see that the solution is working with "basic code". At this point i think the error is somewhere in my code. Thank you for your time.

Comment: In your function, do you know how I can collect the data-target value?
I tried in this way and similar but is not working

$(function() {
  $('#demo3').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
      var getValue = $(this).attr("data-target");
      console.log( getValue );
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#demo3').offset().top - 200
    }, 500);
  });
});